# javascript variable to replace names

Tags: javascript

How can i make so the if else if statement would work as supposed? in this case
`thisminion.optiontable[option]` would be the same call as `thisminion.attack`

i do have the following:

```
var option = 1;

 var optiontable = {1: 'attack', 2: 'defence', 3: 'intelligence'};
            var $result = [];
            var nameoption = optiontable[option];

 if (thisminion.optiontable[option] <= 100) {
                increasement = 10;
            } else if (thisminion.optiontable[option] >= 100 && thisminion.optiontable[option] < 200) {
                increasement = 5;
            } else if (thisminion.optiontable[option] >= 200 && thisminion.optiontable[option] < 300) {
                increasement = 5;
            } else if (thisminion.optiontable[option] >= 300 && thisminion.optiontable[option] < 400) {
                increasement = 1;
            } else {
                increasement = 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you use brackets notation with `optiontable[option]` as the operand:

```
if (thisminion[optiontable[option]] <= 100) {
```

That gets the *value* of `optiontable[option]` (`'attack'`) and uses it to look up the `attack` property of `thisminion`.

This is exactly the same thing you're doing when looking up `optiontable[option]`; using the *value* of `option` to look up a property on `optiontable` with that name (`1`, in that case).

Example:

```js
var option = 1;

var optiontable = {1: 'attack', 2: 'defence', 3: 'intelligence'};

var thisminion = {
  attack: 75,
  defence: 100,
  intelligence: 25
};

console.log(thisminion[optiontable[option]]);
```